# Ubuntu USB disk

Tags: 18.04

I am using windows 10 and want to create a Ubuntu live storage USB.I want to create one of these so I can try Ubuntu to see learn how to use it before I make the switch from windows if I do.

Thanks,
Jimmy

Comment: This seems like a Search Engine question. You will get answers like https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: I see intent. Not a problem we can answer ;)

Comment: Do you want to install on an USB hard drive or just burn the installer to an USB flash drive and use the "Try Ubuntu" option?  Using the try ubuntu option is good to see if all your hard ware works and to see if you like it, but does not save any changes/downloads/ or updates.

Answer (score 0):

Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .